# Drawing 3D diagrams in LaTeX

Tags: diagrams, technical-drawing

I'm currently writing my bachelor's thesis and I'm having trouble with 3D diagrams. Up until now, I was using Inkscape but I was not satisfied with the look of it. Especially with the look of the arrows. I would be very happy if someone has any suggestions as to what application I should use.

That's what I want my diagrams to look like:
[image]
I have also tried TikZ, but it takes too much time.

Comment: If the look of the arrows is really important to you, you should take look at the Inkscape docs: [Creating Custom Markers](https://inkscape-manuals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/custom-markers.html)

Comment: You might take a look at `pstricks`, more precisely to the `pst-solides3d` package

Answer (score 3):

Drawing the figure with Ti*k*Z does not take too long. Maybe it does for Ti*k*Z new users, but it is time well invested because in the long run you will be able to make drawings like this in a short time.

For example, the 3d part would be something like this, using isometric perspective:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}                   % for canvas is... options
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings} % for arrows at midpath

% isometric perspective
\pgfmathsetmacro\xx{1/sqrt(2)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\xy{1/sqrt(6)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\zz{sqrt(2/3)}
\tikzset
{%
  isometric/.style={x={(-\xx cm,-\xy cm)},y={(\xx cm,-\xy cm)},z={(0cm,\zz cm)}},
% arrows
  my arrow/.style 2 args={decoration={markings,mark=at position #1 with
                          {\node[right] {$#2$}; \arrow{stealth}}},                                          
                          postaction={decorate}},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[isometric,scale=2]
% axes
\draw[dashed] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) coordinate (X);
\draw[dashed] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) coordinate (Y);
\draw[dashed] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) coordinate (Z);
\draw[-latex] (X) -- (2,0,0) node [left]  {$x$};
\draw[-latex] (Y) -- (0,2,0) node [right] {$y$};
\draw[-latex] (Z) -- (0,0,2) node [above] {$z$};
% equator
\begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0,blue]
  \draw                 (-45:1) arc (-45:135:1);
  \draw[loosely dashed] (315:1) arc (315:135:1);
\end{scope}
% meridian
\begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0,red]
  \draw[thick,my arrow={0.7}{4}] (-45:1) arc (-45: 90:1);
  \path[thick,my arrow={0.9}{2}] ( 90:1) arc ( 90:-45:1);
  \draw[thick,dashed]            (-90:1) arc (-90:-45:1);
  \draw                          ( 90:1) arc ( 90:135:1);
  \draw[dashed]                  (135:1) arc (135:270:1);
  
\end{scope}
% sphere
\draw (0,0,0) circle (1cm);
% dots
\foreach\z in {1,3}
  \fill[red] (0,0,2-\z) circle (0.5pt) node[below right] {$\z$};
\foreach\i in {X,Y}
  \fill (\i) circle (0.5pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can imagine is the package `tikz-3dplot`. You can take a look at the documentation at the following link: [tikz-3dplot_documenation](https://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-3dplot/tikz-3dplot_documentation.pdf).
You can also check this example which uses the same package for the figure produced: [tikz-3dplot_example](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/the-3dplot-package/).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer. You can try

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3dtools}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[3d/install view={phi=110,theta=70},line cap=butt,
    line join=round,declare function={R=2.5;},c/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt}] 
    \tikzset
    {axis/.style={blue,- latex}};
    \path
    (0,0,0) coordinate (O)
    (0,0,R)  coordinate (N)
    (0,0,-R)  coordinate (S);
    \path[save named path=sph,3d/screen coords] (O) circle[radius=R];
    \path pic{3d/circle on sphere={R=R,C={(O)}}};
    \path  pic{3d/circle on sphere={R=R,C={(O)},P={(O)}, n={(1,-9,0)}}}; 
    
    \path[save named path=ox] (0,0,0) -- (R+5,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
    \path [save named path=oy] (0,0,0) -- (0,R+2,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
    \path [save named path=oz] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,R+1.5) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
    \draw[3d/hidden] (S) -- (O);
        \tikzset{3d/ordered paths/.cd,ox/.style={blue,- latex},oy/.style={blue,- latex},oz/.style={blue,-latex}}
    \tikzset{3d/draw ordered paths={ox,oy,oz,sph}}
    \path foreach \p/\g in {O/-30,S/0,N/-30}
    {(\p)node[c]{}+(\g:2.5mm) node{$\p$}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]